# Creating comment via wordpress rest api returns "confilict - duplicate comment"

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I have a list of comments with different body and author name and I'm trying to create comment via wordpress rest api. The comments should create for one post and the problem is after creating first comment the other requests returns duplicate comment code with 409 status.

I have read topics that mentioned how to disable wordpress duplicate comment detection by editing core files but I can not edit core files.

Answer (score 0):

By adding this filter in function.php duplicate comment detection will be disabled

```
add_filter('duplicate_comment_id', '__return_false');
```